# save and restore dynamic form value after ajax refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax

Got a page where users make comments on any desired post. Each post has a form with just one textarea field created dynamically from js and I'm wondering if anyone has an idea on how to save and restore the comment being typed by a user (i.e save whatever a user has typed so far before ajax refreshes the div holding all the post and comments and then restore back after the div refresh)

Tried creating something around this but not getting it to work:

```
<textarea id="comment_field" onKeyUp="return saveAndRestoreTypedStrings(this)"></textarea>

or  

<textarea id="comment_field" onchange="saveAndRestoreTypedStrings(' + id + ');"></textarea>
```

The function:

```
function saveAndRestoreTypedStrings(id){
   document.getElementById("post_comment").onchange = function() {
     localStorage['post_comment'] = document.getElementById(id).value;
    }
    window.onload= function(){
        if(localStorage['post_comment'])
            document.getElementById(id).value = localStorage['post_comment'];
    }   
}
```

To identify the form a user is on, a unique id for that form had to be passed to the saveAndRestoreTypedStrings(id) function.

For clarity, ajax only refreshes the div holding all the posts and comments made on each post. So, that div is refreshed for latest posts and comment every 3 seconds and if a user is typing to make a comment on a post and ajax reloads the div content, the user loses whatever is being typed.

Would be pleased to get ideas around this....

Comment: BTW: You never need to use "javascript:" in an event handler. You can ONLY use JavaScript.

Comment: Oh thanks...edited the question...U got any better way to achieve this cos i cant get it to work based on what i came up with in the question???

Comment: The whole point of AJAX is that the page DOES NOT refresh. You are not processing your form properly. If the page IS refreshing then you're using the regular-old browser POST.

Comment: Oh nope..the page does not refresh rather ajax refreshes a div containing post and each post comes with a form for comment... so whenever ajax refresh that div content, whatever is being typed in any of the comment form would be lost. so i just need to make sure after ajax reloads the div content, it does not affect the form field for comment (i.e user would not lose whatever has been typed before ajax refreshes for latest content)... I hope u understand what the challenge is..

Comment: Then change the code so it doesn't refresh the DIV.

Comment: ^ Maybe keep your main post <div> and then add two divs inside of it, one for the post content, and one for the textboxes etc. Then you can target just the post content for refresh.

Answer (score 0):

window.onload fires up when the page is completly loaded soo i dont think this would apply for your case.

why dont you try using a callback function after AJAX is complete so you can "restore" the info by calling localStorage ?

Note: sorry, i cant comment yet.